# SPServices geting items from list

Tags: spservices

I need to get a number of fields from my list. I've got the ID but dont know how to get the Title, Created by, Customer Name. etc. Once I get these values I want to populate the form.

Code so far that gets ID

```
    var lastId = $().SPServices.SPGetLastItemId({ 
    listName: "myList"
  });
```

Comment: sorry what ? can you explain your question properly please

Answer (score 4):

I think you are talking about the Jquery SPServices library, you should start by reading the spservices documentation here:

http://spservices.codeplex.com/documentation

I'll give you a code sample, but to get this really working you need to read the documentation.

```
function GetEvents() {
    $().SPServices({
        debug: true,
        operation: "GetListItems",
        async: false,
        webURL: '/',
        listName: "Events",
        completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
            $(xData.responseXML).find("[nodeName='z:row']").each(function () {
                events.push({
                    Id: $(this).attr("ows_ID"),
                    Nombre: $(this).attr("ows_Title"),
                    Descripcion: $(this).attr("ows_Description"),
                    TipoEvento: $(this).attr("ows_EventType"),
                });
            });
        }
    });
}
```